# Laravel - Getting count from many-to-many table

Tags: laravel, count, many-to-many

So I want to get a count of all the projects in different stages for an employee ($id). So something like:

Queued - 3
In Progress - 7
Launched - 5

I have a projects table and an employees table and an employee_project table.

How can I get the stages for the projects for a particular employee? This does not work as it lists out every status and just 1 next to it:

```
@foreach ($employee->projects as $project)
   <h3>{{ $project->stage }}</h3>
   <h3>{{ count($project->stage) }}</h3>
@endforeach
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have method in the Employee model:

```
public function projectsByStage() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project')->groupBy('stage');
}
```

This will get the employee's projects grouped by project stage.

Then in your blade template

```
@foreach ($employee->projectsByStage as $stage => $projects)
   <h3>{{ $stage }}</h3>
   <h3>{{ count($projects) }}</h3>
@endforeach
```

**Edit:**

I think you don't need another method. You can directly do this:

```
@foreach ($employee->projects->groupBy('stage') as $stage => $projects)
   <h3>{{ $stage }}</h3>
   <h3>{{ count($projects) }}</h3>
@endforeach
```

[groupBy method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby)